# How to set checkbox as check by default in an MFC dialog application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, mfc, default

I'm trying to set some check boxes as checked by default in my MFC dialog when it runs.

I have created a `CButton` variable for the check box called `m_check`.
Next I added `m_check.SetCheck` in `OnInitDialog`.

```
BOOL CModelDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    ....
    m_check.SetCheck;
    ....
```

The error always appears:

> Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function.

I'm not sure what this error means. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out in case anybody wants to know. Add this in `OnInitDialog`:

```
CButton* pBtn = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_XXXXXX);
pBtn->SetCheck(1);
```

Comment: You can also use the constants FALSE and TRUE. And, you can also map the control to a BOOL variable and default to TRUE and then use UpdateData().

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot parenthesis in the SetCheck function. It should be

```
BOOL CModelDlg::OnInitDialog() {
....
m_check.SetCheck(TRUE);
....
```